# Sort a dictionary based on alphanumeric keys

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has alphanumeric keys and I need to sort them based on increasing order of numeric value of the key.Below is my dictionary

```
output_filters = {"filter22": "red", "filter13": "green", "filter36": "yellow"}
```

I want the final dictionary to be sorted like below

```
output_filters = {"filter13": "green", "filter22": "red", "filter36": "yellow"}
```

Now I know there are similar stackoverflow questions out there but I am not able to adapt it to my situation.

This is what I have done so far, but it doesn't work

```
def key_func(s):
    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.findall(r'\D+|\d+', s)]

sorted_keys = sorted(output_filters, key=key_func)
```

It gives inaccurate result.How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you a sorted `List` of keys.

```
x = [k for k, v in output_filters.items()]

x = sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(x[6:])) # this will remove "filter" prefix

# ['filter13', 'filter22', 'filter36']
```

However, you can't sort a dictionary. They are unordered. If you really need it to be sorted, then you will need to use `OrderedDict`. It is an official built-in module that comes with python itself.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: This doesn't sort the keys based on the numeric value in `filter`. What if `x`  contains the key `filter113`?

Comment: @AlanSTACK Hey I need the dictionary to be sorted on the basis of keys and it has been done in certain stackoverflow posts.I just need to adapt it to my situation.

Comment: @SouvikRay Have you considered getting the keys out of the dictionary, sorting them, then iterating over the keys and accessing the dictionary that way?

Comment: @Wondercricket any idea?

Comment: @SouvikRay `x = sorted(x, key=lambda x: int(x[6:]))`